# How do I transform a file of integers in a list of lists

Tags: prolog, swi-prolog

I have a file as follows (numbers separate by space and rows end with a dot):

```
4554 3332 3 23 344.     
4 2 3 5 7 86 56.     
7 8 1 4 66.
```

and I would like to create a list of lists, one list for each row like this:

```
[[4554,3332,3,23,344],[4,2,3,5,7,86,56],[7,8,1,4,66]]
```

how can I do? 
thank you very much

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend using a definite clause grammar (DCG) and the DCG/basics library, like this:

```
:- use_module(library(dcg/basics)).
:- use_module(library(pio)).

number_line([]) --> ".".
number_line([N|Ns]) --> integer(N), whites, number_line(Ns).

file([Line|Lines]) --> number_line(Line), blanks, file(Lines).
file([]) --> [].
```

Then you can parse the whole file at once with a simple predicate like this:

```
parse_integer_file(File, Lists) :-
    phrase_from_file(file(Lists), File).
```

Trying it out with your example data in `file.txt`:

```
?- parse_integer_file('input.txt', R).
R = [[4554, 3332, 3, 23, 344], [4, 2, 3, 5, 7, 86, 56], [7, 8, 1, 4, 66]] .
```

There are several advantages to this approach:

- The library DCG rules are battle-tested and work
- This grammar is therefore already resilient against extra spaces and extra blank lines
- The code is short and easier to read than the corresponding manual input/output and splitting
- The pure I/O facility that provides `parse_from_file/2` is very efficient

Comment: Very nice, +1. Additional advantage: You can test the DCG interactively and add self-contained unit-tests even without any file.